# Unity - character falling faster than jumping

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement my own gravity for a character.
But for some unknown to me reason the character's landing speed is higher landing than when jumping, by quite a lot (~15 initial jump speed, ~24 final land speed). I'm ultimately trying to replicate behavior shown on the gif below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U24Hm.jpg

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 3;
    public float jumpSpeed = 15;
    public float gravity = -1f;


    private float ySpeed = 0;
    private float jumpTime = 0;
    private bool direction = false; //true for going up, false for falling down - gravity
    private bool previousDirection = false; //to keep track of changing direction

    private CharacterController _characterController;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        float dx = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float dz = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float dy = Input.GetAxis("Jump");

//        move around        
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(dx, 0, dz);

//        limit diagonal movement
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, 1);
//        speed
        movement *= speed;


//        change of direction
        if(ySpeed>0 && direction!=true)
            direction = true;
        else if(ySpeed<0 && direction!=false)
            direction = false;

//        if changed direction - peak of the jump
        if(direction!=previousDirection){
            Debug.Log("Jump Time = " + jumpTime);
            jumpTime = Time.deltaTime;
            previousDirection = direction;
        }

//        jump/on ground
        if(_characterController.isGrounded) {
            ySpeed = -0.5f;
            jumpTime = 0;

            if(dy > 0f){
                ySpeed = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
//        gravity - when not on ground
        else{
//            dv/dt
            ySpeed += gravity*jumpTime;
//            add jump time
            jumpTime += Time.deltaTime;

            // Debug.Log(jumpTime);
            Debug.Log(ySpeed);
        }

        movement.y = ySpeed;

//        direction adjustment
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);

        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        _characterController.Move(movement);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what was wrong with my idea.
`ySpeed += gravity*jumpTime`

So every frame I'm adding more and more acceleration downwards. This should just be:   `ySpeed += gravity *Time.deltaTime`
(Acceleration due to gravity is then constant, not getting greater as time passes)

It is being integrated over many steps, so each Update() cycle is a slice of time that adds some velocity based on acceleration due to gravity, multiplied by the amount of time taken by that little slice.

In another words...
Gravity is a constant acceleration. I've made it a linear function of the time spent in the air. So, I start the jump with no gravity and end the jump with very high gravity.

Comment: According to my limited math knowledge: Velocity = rate of change of position (i.e position += velocity * timeInterval); Acceleration = rate of change of velocity (i.e. velocity += acceleration * timeInterval).